# Animating MagicaVoxel model with separate parts in Blender

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

I'm a beginner on Blender and I'm trying to animate a model from MagicaVoxel on Blender but I'm having problems with the skeleton and weight painting.

I imported the obj file I got from MagicaVoxel and added a skeleton, but I got a problem, some faces of the model are getting deformed too much when rotating a part.
[image]

The bottom of the character is deformed when moving the foot and it looks weird. I tried reducing the weight paint on the body so it wouldn't deform but I always have a small part of the body that is deforming.

Is there an easier way to animate characters like this? Should I really use a skeleton for a simple character like that? I'm gonna use the model on Unity after making the animations, is there a better workflow than MagicaVoxel -> Blender -> Unity?